# FreeLibrary() causing access violation error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, wrapper

I have a wrapper class that wraps functions in an DLL.  Naturally, I use `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` to load and free the DLL. When my wrapper management object gets created, it runs a `Startup()` function:

```
//at the top
#define AVTCAM_DLL_NAME (L"VimbaBridgeAPI.dll")

//startup()
void CAVTcamDllWrapper::Startup()
{
    mAVTCamLibrary = LoadLibrary(AVTCAM_DLL_NAME);
    if(mAVTCamLibrary == NULL)
    {
        //report an error
    }
}
```

Then, when the wrapper manager gets deleted, it calls the shutdown function in its destructor:

```
void CAVTcamDllWrapper::Shutdown()
{
    if(mAVTCamLibrary != NULL)
    {
       FreeLibrary(mAVTCamLibrary);
       mAVTCamLibrary = NULL; //for extra safety
    }
}
```

**Here is my problem:** the camera I am working with can startup just fine.  The problem is during the shutdown, and more specifically, during the `FreeLibrary()` call.  As soon as the FreeLibrary gets called, the next line of code always fails.

In this case, my debugger shows that it executed FreeLibrary and it jumps to the `mAVTCamLibrary = NULL;` line, then that line will result in an *Access Violation Error*.

If I get rid of the `mAVTCamLibrary = NULL;` line (which I did at first because I thought this line was causing the error), then whatever my debugger jumps to after the FreeLibrary() causes an access violation error.

I cannot figure out why I get these errors right after calling FreeLibrary().  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sounds like a typical memory overflow, use after free or similar error. Check the value of `mAVTCamLibrary` after opening the library and at the point you are closing it.

Comment: You are still using the library somehow. We can't quite tell how from just the code you pasted.

Comment: Do you have another thread running that's using the DLL?

Comment: @RogerRowland Not that I have found yet.  All other threads halt when the camera is switching.